# F# Adding value to map result in KeyNotFoundException

Tags: f#

```
type bytesLookup = Map<byte,int list>
type lookupList = bytesLookup list

let maps:bytesLookup = Map.empty

let printArg arg = printfn(Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>(arg))

let array1 = [|byte(0x02);byte(0xB1);byte(0xA3);byte(0x02);byte(0x18);byte(0x2F)|]

let InitializeNew(maps:bytesLookup,element,index) =
    maps.Add(element,List.empty<int>)(*KeyNotFoundException*)
    maps.[element]

let MapArray (arr:byte[],maps:bytesLookup ) =
   for i in 0..arr.Length do
       match maps.TryFind(arr.[i]) with
        | Some(e) -> i::e
        | None -> InitializeNew(maps,arr.[i],i)

MapArray(array1,maps);

printArg( maps.Count.ToString())
```

Exception

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not
>   present in the dictionary.    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.MapTreeModule.find[TValue,a](IComparer`1
>   comparer, TValue k, MapTree`2 m)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpMap`2.get_Item(TKey key)    at
>   FSI_0012.MapArray(Byte[] arr, FSharpMap`2 maps) in Script1.fsx:line 16
>   at .$FSI_0012.main@() in Script1.fsx:line 20

In the function I'm trying to initialize a new element in the map with a list of int. I also try to push a new int value into the list at the same time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's `bytesLookup` supposed to be?  Also, `index :: List.empty<int>` is not very concise, you can just write `[index]`.

Comment: This error is raised when you try to *read*, not write. Post the full exception, including the call stack.

Comment: @TheInnerLight sorry, I forgot to include the definition. update my question. 
I'm too new to this thing. can you post an answer where I should write this index? Thanks.

Comment: It seems most likely that you're forgetting that an F# Map is immutable and you're trying to get the element you've added from the original map, rather than the map returned by `maps.Add`.  You haven't posted any code where you read from the map though

Comment: No repro when I try to call the function with `InitializeNew(maps,6uy,5)`. Post the code that actually throws the exception and the full exception text, including the call stack. This will show which method actually caused the exception

Comment: @Esh the call stack shows that the exception is thrown when you try to *read* from a map. Most likely this means you are trying to read from the *wrong* map.

Comment: Edited my question to include all the script. Sorry for the confusion, first day with f# for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# `Map` is an immutable data structure, the `Add` method doesn't modify the existing data structure, it returns a new `Map` with the additions you've requested.

Observe:

```
let ex1 = 
    let maps = Map.empty<byte, int list>
    maps.Add(1uy, [1]) // compiler warning here!
    maps.[1uy]
```

Two things about this code:

1. It throws `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException` when you run it
2. It gives you a compiler warning that the line `maps.Add...` should have type `unit` but actually has type `Map<byte,int list>`.  Don't ignore the warning!

Now try this:

```
let ex2 =
    let maps = Map.empty<byte, int list>
    let maps2 = maps.Add(1uy, [1])
    maps2.[1uy]
```

No warning.  No exception.  Code works as expected, returning the value `[1]`.

Comment: @Esh No problem.  This is a common pattern you will see in functional languages like F#.  You can check out the wikipedia article on persistent data structures for some more background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure